# Is there a better way to make tables in Craft?

Tags: redactor, table

I'm using the table function built into Redactor, and all my tables are coming out with the minimum width possible, without any padding between columns. How do I modify how Redactor builds its tables?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a [Table](https://craftcms.com/docs/table-fields) or [SuperTable](https://github.com/engram-design/SuperTable) field

But if you want to stick to a Redactor Rich Text field, put a wrapper `<div>` around the `{{ entry.redactorField }}` Twig markup, and use CSS to style the table ala `.myRedactorWrapper th` etc.

Comment: Table and Super Table are much better ways to do tables in Craft, and if you need columns to be configurable there’s [Table Maker](http://plugins.supercooldesign.co.uk/plugin/table-maker).

Comment: Its all part of a matric field that has image, rich text, quote, etc. I guess i could make a seperate entry in the matrix just for inserting a table and use table. Ill try that!